# Implementing the All / Universal set

Tags: python, set

In order to simplify my code, I would like to implement a set that contains *everything*, i.e. a `UniversalSet`. I figure that the simplest of way of getting around this is to have a custom set that returns True for any query. In my particular case I am mostly interested in the `__intersect__` of sets such that the following criteria are true:

```
u_set = UniversalSet()
u_set & {1, 2, 3} == {1, 2, 3}  # (1)
{1, 2, 3} & u_set == {1, 2, 3}  # (2)
```

I have subclassed `set` in the following manner:

```
class UniversalSet(set):
    def __and__(self, other):
        return other
```

This works for `(1)`, but `(2)` still fails. Is there a similarly easy way to make `(2)` to work?

Comment: its called a universal set by the way

Comment: Nice, didn't know that. Here's a link to other methods one can consider overriding in order to add similar functionality to other set operations: http://fiber-space.de/wordpress/2009/04/16/universal-set-in-python/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need to define the *reversed* version of the and operator (`__rand__`) so your subclasses methods get called when it is the second argument as well as the first.

```
class UniversalSet(set):
    def __and__(self, other):
        return other

    def __rand__(self, other):
        return other
```

Comment: I don't think these should be class methods. It just happens to work because `self` is unused.

Comment: This works, perfectly. @interjay, true, it appears it is not needed.

Comment: @interjay: you mean *instance* methods, yes strictly they don't *need* to be, since `self` is being thrown away, so functionally they should reduce to being classmethods, yet they still syntactically require a LHS argument `self` even though they ignore it. We implicitly dance around defining `UniversalSet.__init__()` since we can't implement a general one, and we intend it would only ever be lazily evaluated anyway. Most other methods of `UniversalSet` either have similarly trivial implementations, or can't be implemented (e.g. `__iter__`, `__len__`)

Comment: @smci The original version of the question used `@classmethod` incorrectly, which is what my comment was about. I'm guessing that this answer used the same and was edited within the grace period so it isn't shown in edit history..

Comment: def __contains__(self, other): return True